# Сетевое хранилище NetGear ReadyNAS - некорректно работает web-интерфейс и нет возможности обновить прошивку

Tags: nas

Есть сетевое хранилище NetGear ReadyNAS 3200. При попытке зайти на web-интерфейс, выдается экран без каких-либо надписей, кнопок, и прочих элементов управления.
[image: скриншот]
 Пробовал заходить с разных браузеров, с разных компьютеров с различными операционными системами - результат тот же. Пробовал хард ресет и OS Reinstall - не помогает. Техподдержка NetGear отказалась помочь, мотивируя это тем, что необходимо приобретать платную услугу поддержки. Обновить прошивку нет возможности кроме как из этого web-интерфейса, который не работает. TelNet и SSH заблокированы, разблокировать их можно также только через web-интерфейс, который не работает. Замкнутый круг. Может кто сталкивался с подобным и подскажет как реанимировать web-интерфейс, либо обновить прошивку? Спасибо.

Comment: У вас есть физический доступ к хранилищу? Как Капитан Очевидность, предполагаю, что, судя по тому, что в спецификации к нему указано наличие *RS232 console port*, то можно попробовать подключиться так, там уже посмотреть на предоставляемую функциональность.

Comment: А вариант «сдать девайс назад тому, у кого покупали» не подходит?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ответам комьюнити Netgear, встречающимся в интернете ([1](https://community.netgear.com/t5/Using-your-ReadyNAS/solved-Duo-Frontview-with-ReadyNAS-null/td-p/863703),[2](https://community.netgear.com/t5/Using-your-ReadyNAS/ReadyNas-Admin-FrontView-Panel-Null/td-p/949438)), проблема действительно может быть в несовместимости браузеров. Вы какие браузеры пробовали, современные? Попробуйте версии постарее.

Решением проблемы может быть использование режима TechSupportMode и `telnet`, соответственно, - вы как раз попадете в консоль (правда, нет достоверной информации, поддерживает ли данный режим именно эта модель устройства). Инструкция от NetGear [прилагается](http://netgear.nas-central.org/wiki/TechSupportMode).

Также, если вы не пробовали подключиться к консоли физически через *RS232*, то попробуйте, это может помочь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.